# `Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined` in React

Tags: reactjs, facebook

I have added Facebook login api into React app

```
// index.html
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="https://connect.facebook.net..." etc... />
  <script>
    const FB = window.FB;
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({etc...});
      FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    }
  </script>
  etc...
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

And then another one in the React provider

```
// SomeProvider.js
const SomeProvider = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.FB.getLoginStatus((res) => {etc...});
  }, []);
  etc...
}
```

The error message I'm getting is that FB is not defined in `SomeProvider.js` and then another same message for `react-dom.production.min.js`.

I don't understand why.

---

## Update

When I repeatedly refresh, sometimes that error doesn't appear, which makes me think that this is an asynchronous issue.  It seems that `window.FB.getLoginStatus` needs to wait until `FB.init` in `index.html` is done.  Am I correct with this assessment? Any recommendations regarding this?

Answer (score -1):

you may try add [window.FB] as deps of useEffect of someprovide